# Is it OK to post puzzles that require to play a game?

Tags: discussion

Would it be OK for me to post a puzzle that requires to research about, or even play, a free, short game in order to be able to solve it?

I'm not the creator of this game nor am I in any way affiliated with it, so it wouldn't fall under promotion of my *own* product. But I guess it could still be considered promotion of another product and the puzzle wouldn't really be solvable just by the text posted, so I'm not sure if this would be a good fit for the site. I would give a big hint which indicates that the puzzle strongly depends on knowledge about this game, though.

Comment: One concern I have is that if the game ever stops being available, the puzzle will not be solvable.

Comment: @f'' Right - this is exactly why link-only answers are frowned upon across all of SE. Link rot can be a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needing research is fine. There are tons of [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) puzzles and even more that require you to look up things.

Honestly, I wouldn't have *too* much of an issue with it, though we may have to discuss further depending on what the puzzle actually is. My only real concern is inaccessibility if the linked site goes down.

Comment: What should I do in case the site goes down? Since it (hopefully) would have upvoted answers until then, I can't delete it anymore. Are moderators able to delete questions without the answerers losing reputation?

Comment: @LukasRotter: Unfortunately not. If you were fairly sure that the site was stable, it shouldn't be a problem. Also, if you could include all the "rules" of the game in the post, then you should do so. ([Puzzlescript](http://www.puzzlescript.net/) is a great tool for things like this.)